# Caddy + Organizr + Plex Media Server = Can't connect to PMS?

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, caddy, plex, caddyfile

Ultimately my goal is to be able to load my PMS admin interface via Organizr. I had already tried simply using the URL `https://app.plex.tv/desktop` through Organizr, but that URL disallows loading the page in iFrames, so now I'm trying to use Caddy server to reverse proxy it to my local LAN IP instead ...

I have this code in my `Caddyfile` (*note that my PMS is hosted on a different pc on my LAN*):

```
proxy /pms https://192.168.234.234:32400 {
  websocket
  keepalive 12
  header_upstream Host {host}
  header_upstream X-Real-IP {remote}
  header_upstream X-Forwarded-For {remote}
  header_upstream X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
  transparent
}
```

Then when I try to visit the URL, it gives me a `502 Bad Gateway`, and the Caddy log file says `[ERROR 502 /pms] x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.234.234 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs`

If I add the `insecure_skip_verify` directive, I get the error: `401 Unauthorized` instead.

I'm still pretty new to using Caddy, anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my particular problem; in Organizer I used the Plex web URL instead.

`https://192.168.234.234:32400/web`

Note the `/web` at the end.

Another option, was to have Organizr open it using the `PopOut` option, which just acts something like a regular bookmark, and loads any URL in a new tab, and/or add a line to the Caddyfile like this:

`redir /pms https://app.plex.tv/desktop 301`

Then in Organizr you could use either the `/pms` URL, or the direct Plex URL `https://app.plex.tv/desktop`, and it'd just load Plex in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use *Caddy* which will deal with the SSL, redirect to **http** instead of http**s**.